# How do I get "I" to increment inside a .click function

Tags: javascript

```
$('#x').click(function() {
var i=1;

    $('#y').prepend('<div id='+i+'>x'+i+'</div>');
    i++;        
});
```

I want the i to increment, now for some reason it is not.  I will agree this is a silly question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place `var i` before the `click` scope:

```
var i=1;
$('#x').click(function() {
    $('#y').prepend('<div id='+i+'>x'+i+'</div>');
    i++;        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try not to litter the global scope. This solution will encapsulate i, but still retain its value

```
$('#x').click((function() {
    var i = 1;
    return function () {
        $('#y').prepend('<div id='+i+'>x'+i+'</div>');
        i++;        
    }
})());
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Hxw3q/

Comment: Then you could use multiple "I" around?

Comment: Yeah - `i` is only available within that function, instead of everywhere. This means that - like you said - it won't interfere with other uses of `i` in your application.

Comment: The outer, immediately-invoked function is to create a scope for i. This is because in JavaScript, it is only functions that create scope for variables